# Appium cannot find by ID, can by Xpath

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I am able to find elements by XPath but not by Id. I have tried in many ways as shown below

```
// I have tried everything below with By as well as MobileBy
            var list = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("com.PACKAGE:id/ID"));
            var list = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("PACKAGE:id/ID"));
            var list = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("android:id/ID"));
            var list = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("ID"));

            var list = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.Id("com.PACKAGE:id/ID"));
            var list = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.Id("PACKAGE:id/ID"));
            var list = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.Id("android:id/ID"));
            var list = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.Id("ID"));

// This does find an element, but using the XPath will be not realistic
            string xpath = "FULL_XPATH_FROM_APPIUM_INSPECTOR";
            var xpathList = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.XPath(xpath));
// This returns a random GUID, different every time, just like shown in image below
            var x = xpathList[0].Id;
// This then finds nothing. Also with the other methods from above (android:id/... etc.)
            var list = driver.FindElements(MobileBy.Id(x));
```

The correct Id is shown in Appium Inspector. Bare in mind, it only shows the Id, it doesn't show "android:id/ID" or "com.PACKAGE:id/ID" or any other method. The element-id in Appium, is shown as a random Guid every time, always different so un-useable. I did find this which I think is to do with this: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/276#issuecomment-335904845

[image]

Also, if I copy this Guid, and try to search by Id using that, it doesn't find anything (either in code or in the Appium Inspector itself)

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = driver.FindElements(
    MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches(\".*ID.*\")")
);
```

Using the above code allows you to locate the correct Id. The problem is that the driver is looking for a different Id, I didn't find out which, but this will do.

If someone has a more comprehensive answer that would be great